# Is there a better way to reference something at the end of a block of text?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a situation where I want to comment on something at the end of a block of text, rather then as a footnote:[image: The statblock I am formatting]

I've done this by leaving as the origional author did, with a * after Language: Any, and a * before Gailteach, but I'm wondering if there is a better, more LaTeXy way of doing this, as this seems very...ugly, codewise. It also doesn't link the two points together in anyway, though I could do that manually with Hyperref if the suggested solution doesn't have that built in.

Here is a MWE of what I've done:

```
%Page layout here
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left= 2.2 cm, right=2.2 cm, top = 2.2 cm, bottom = 2.2 cm]{geometry}

%Font stuff here
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[]{venturis}

%Goddamn tables.
\usepackage{booktabs}                          %Makes the pretty table based on wikibooks example

%Load last stuff.
\usepackage{hyperref}                          %Adds a PDF index & makes links clickable: LOAD LAST



\begin{document}
{\small
\noindent\textbf{Morph:} Menton\\
\textbf{Skills:} Academics: Linguistics 85, Academics: Neurolinguistics 80, Art: Logograms 50,
Interests: Accents 60, Interests: Dialects 75, Interests: Synthetic Languages 80, Interests:
Xenolinguistics 80, Interfacing 50, Investigation 50, Language: Native Gaelic 95,
Language: Any*, Networking: Firewall 25, Networking: Scientists 25, Profession:
Interpreter 75 Profession: Linguist: 80, Profession: Teacher 60, Profession: Translator 65,
Research 77\\
\textbf{Implants:} Basic Biomods, Basic Mesh Inserts, Cortical Stack, Eidetic Memory, Hyper-Linguist, Math Boost, Multi-tasking, Oracles\\
\textbf{Traits:} Fast Learner, Mental Disorder (Severe phobia of psychosurgery), Neural Damage (Amnesia, Blackouts)\\
*Gailteach knows hundreds of human languages and dialects; common languages (Arabic, English, French, Hindi, Japanese, Mandarin, etc.) have a typical rating of 75; 
uncommon languages 60, and synthetic \& obscure languages (Esperanto, Klingon, Sumerian, \&c.) 50.
}

\end{document}
```

I'm sure I want this at the end of the statblock, not as a footnote, which may be less typographically correct, makes it much easier for the gamemaster to reference during play.

Comment: as it is, it doesn't really stand out.  for a really ad hoc approach, add a small bit of space just before it, by adding, e.g., `[2pt]` just after the `\\` that precedes it.  but it would probably be better to define "heading" commands rather than the totally ad hoc `\noindent\textbf{...}` and explicit line breaks you've used here (the result doesn't have to look any different), and then define a separate command for a "note" such as this.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I would, except I'm not good enough with Regex to avoid having to go and change about 60 of these things by hand, whereas the find and replace to get them into the current form from the raw text is pretty easy. So while I agree that in principle the way jon outlines with a command is better, the ad hoc solution is a heck of a lot easier to do in an existing document.

Comment: Either way, +1 for “&c”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hah, thanks. To be honest, it isn't my writing, just something I'm converting into LaTeX for someone, though I'veused &c. on occasion myself. However, I do find it a bit of an anachronism in an SF setting, but hey, its cool. 

That said, I just removed the one above, as I didn't want both etc and &c in the same paragraph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest the [parnotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parnotes) package.  (I also took the liberty to refactor how you are encoding your character information a little bit, which you are free to ignore.)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left= 2.2 cm, right=2.2 cm, top = 2.2 cm, bottom = 2.2 cm]{geometry}

%Font stuff here
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{venturis}

%Goddamn special notes
\usepackage[
notessf,     % default: roman
% breakwithin, % default: paragraph notes
]{parnotes}

%Goddamn tables.
\usepackage{booktabs}

% etc.
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

%Load last stuff.
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\headfont}{\bfseries\sffamily\color{Maroon}}% <-- whatever you like
\newcommand*{\morph}[1]{{\headfont Morph:} #1}
\newcommand*{\skills}[1]{{\headfont Skills:} #1}
\newcommand*{\implants}[1]{{\headfont Implants:} #1}
\newcommand*{\traits}[1]{{\headfont Traits:} #1}

%% this command assumes each character has exactly the same list of major categories (not sure if this is true...)
\newcommand{\chardesc}[4]{%
  \small\noindent
  \morph{#1}\newline
  \skills{#2}\newline
  \implants{#3}\newline
  \traits{#4}
\par\parnotes}

\begin{document}

\chardesc{Menton}%
{Academics: Linguistics 85, Academics: Neurolinguistics 80, Art:
  Logograms 50, Interests: Accents 60, Interests: Dialects 75,
  Interests: Synthetic Languages 80, Interests: Xenolinguistics 80,
  Interfacing 50, Investigation 50, Language: Native Gaelic 95,
  Language: Any%
  \parnote{Gailteach knows hundreds of human languages and dialects;
    common languages (Arabic, English, French, Hindi, Japanese,
    Mandarin, etc.)  have a typical rating of 75; uncommon languages
    60, and synthetic \& obscure languages (Esperanto, Klingon,
    Sumerian, \&c.) 50.}%
  , Networking: Firewall 25, Networking: Scientists 25, Profession:
  Interpreter 75 Profession: Linguist: 80, Profession: Teacher 60,
  Profession: Translator 65, Research 77%
  \parnote{That is, he hates it, but he knows how to do it.}%
}%
{Basic Biomods, Basic Mesh Inserts, Cortical Stack, Eidetic Memory,
  Hyper-Linguist, Math Boost, Multi-tasking, Oracles}%
{Fast Learner, Mental Disorder (Severe phobia of
  psychosurgery%
  \parnote{And, really, who isn't?}%
  ), Neural Damage
  (Amnesia, Blackouts)}

\bigskip

\chardesc{Menton (without commentary)}%
{Academics: Linguistics 85, Academics: Neurolinguistics 80, Art:
  Logograms 50, Interests: Accents 60, Interests: Dialects 75,
  Interests: Synthetic Languages 80, Interests: Xenolinguistics 80,
  Interfacing 50, Investigation 50, Language: Native Gaelic 95,
  Language: Any, Networking: Firewall 25, Networking: Scientists 25,
  Profession: Interpreter 75 Profession: Linguist: 80, Profession:
  Teacher 60, Profession: Translator 65, Research 77}%
{Basic Biomods, Basic Mesh Inserts, Cortical Stack, Eidetic Memory,
  Hyper-Linguist, Math Boost, Multi-tasking, Oracles}%
{Fast Learner, Mental Disorder (Severe phobia of psychosurgery ),
  Neural Damage (Amnesia, Blackouts)}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought of setting something like that up, but not all characters match exactly, though I suppose I could just leave some ones listing 'none'. Now I have to decide if I want to go back and fix the first 69 pages to use this....

Comment: Or `\newcommand{\traitcat}[2]{{\headfont #1:} #2}` and use repeated `\traitcat{Morph}{Menton}`-like calls in `\chardesc`.  Or, if you want fancy, a key-value approach could be used.  I was trying to keep it simple since I wasn't sure what the exact situation was.

Comment: And, of course, the `parnotes` package would work in your original example!

Comment: That is what I did: I love your example, but the sections do change depending on what the character has, and while I could put in 'none' I'm not nearly good enough to write a regex to convert what I have now into your format, and I don't want to redo 41 statblocks by hand.

Comment: @Canageek -- Understandable.  The gain of re-doing it would only really come into play if you had (lots) more to do.

Comment: Or if I could easily script it to change; the difference is doing 70 of these things by regex + some hand modifications (I have to add the \\ myself to each entry) or having to do the entire thing by hand. If I ever become a regex ninja I might consider redoing it, or if I was writing such things by myself.

Answer (score 5):

Setting things in a `minipage` (based on a [discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10590742#10590742)) is also an option, since `minipage`s have their `\footnote`s grouped at the bottom of them (by default):

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=22mm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

%\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\endminipage}{\unskip}{\vspace*{-.7\baselineskip}\unskip}{}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{% From article.cls
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@.5em{\@makefnmark\hss}#1}%\hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\newenvironment{statblock}
  {%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\@fnsymbol{footnote}}% Footnotes are symbols
  \let\footnoterule\relax% No footnote rule
   \setlength{\footskip}{0pt}\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}\small\strut\ignorespaces}
  {\strut\endminipage}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
{\small
\noindent\textbf{Morph:} Menton\\
\textbf{Skills:} Academics: Linguistics 85, Academics: Neurolinguistics 80, Art: Logograms 50,
Interests: Accents 60, Interests: Dialects 75, Interests: Synthetic Languages 80, Interests:
Xenolinguistics 80, Interfacing 50, Investigation 50, Language: Native Gaelic 95,
Language: Any*, Networking: Firewall 25, Networking: Scientists 25, Profession:
Interpreter 75 Profession: Linguist: 80, Profession: Teacher 60, Profession: Translator 65,
Research 77\\
\textbf{Implants:} Basic Biomods, Basic Mesh Inserts, Cortical Stack, Eidetic Memory, Hyper-Linguist, Math Boost, Multi-tasking, Oracles\\
\textbf{Traits:} Fast Learner, Mental Disorder (Severe phobia of psychosurgery), Neural Damage (Amnesia, Blackouts) \\{}
*Gailteach knows hundreds of human languages and dialects; common languages (Arabic, English, French, Hindi, Japanese, Mandarin, etc.) have a typical rating of 75; 
uncommon languages 60, and synthetic \& obscure languages (Esperanto, Klingon, Sumerian, \&c.) 50.
}

\bigskip

\begin{statblock}
  \textbf{Morph:} Menton \par
  \textbf{Skills:} Academics: Linguistics 85, Academics: Neurolinguistics 80, Art: Logograms 50,
    Interests: Accents 60, Interests: Dialects 75, Interests: Synthetic Languages 80, Interests:
    Xenolinguistics 80, Interfacing 50, Investigation 50, Language: Native Gaelic 95,
    Language: Any\footnote{Gailteach knows hundreds of human languages and dialects; 
      common languages (Arabic, English, French, Hindi, Japanese, Mandarin, etc.) have 
      a typical rating of 75; uncommon languages 60, and synthetic \& obscure languages 
      (Esperanto, Klingon, Sumerian, \&c.) 50.}, Networking: Firewall 25, Networking: 
    Scientists 25, Profession: Interpreter 75 Profession: Linguist: 80, Profession: 
    Teacher 60, Profession: Translator 65, Research 77 \par
  \textbf{Implants:} Basic Biomods, Basic Mesh Inserts, Cortical Stack, Eidetic Memory, 
    Hyper-Linguist, Math Boost, Multi-tasking, Oracles \par
  \textbf{Traits:} Fast Learner, Mental Disorder (Severe phobia of psychosurgery), 
    Neural Damage (Amnesia, Blackouts)
\end{statblock}
\end{document}
```

If is also advisable to define a macro that will set the "characteristic titles", since it allows for easy change later. For line spacing adjustment, I suggest adding the [`setspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) and using `\setstretch` (say).